# Access i18n package data inside the JS with Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, json, meteor, internationalization

I'm looking for some way to access to the data of the tap:i18n Meteor.js's package in order to send emails in the correct language to the user.

Unfortunaly, I can't find anything working on the web about that.

I've tried to access the .json a $.getJSON, without success.

Has someone a solution to this problem ? My coworkers are facing the same problem without finding a solution.

Thanks you,

David

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked the [API docs](https://github.com/TAPevents/tap-i18n/#tapi18n-api)?

As you can see there, you can use `TAPi18n.getLanguage()` on the client. You are probably triggering the email using a Method. So you can just pass an additional argument with the language:

```
Meteor.call('sendMail', 'Hi!', TAPi18n.getLanguage())
```

### Rendering Email using Templates

You could also just render the email HTML client-side using `Blaze.toHTML`. Then you can pass that to the method call.

```
Meteor.call('sendMail', Blaze.toHTML(Template.myMailTemplate))
```

You could also use `Blaze.toHTMLWithData` to pass some data to the email.

### Rendering the Emails Server-Side

If you have a user to which you want to send the email to, you can simply save their language preference inside their profile. So whenever you use `TAPi18n.setLanguage` you'll need to do something like this:

```
Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), { $set: { 'profile.lang': newLang } })
TAPi18n.setLanguage(newLang)
```

On the server you can then either use [`meteorhaks:ssr`](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-ssr):

`server/*.js`

```
var user = // Set this to the object of the user you want to send the mail to
Template.registerHelper('_', TAPi18n._.bind(TAPi18n))
var myEmailHtml = SSR.render('myEmail', { lang: user.profile.lang })
```

`private/myEmail.html`

```
<p>{{ _ 'Hi!' lang }}</p>
```

Or you could just generate the HTML in JavaScript:

```
var user = // Set this to the object of the user you want to send the mail to
var myEmailHtml = ['<p>' '</p>'].join(TAPi18n._('Hi!', user.profile.lang))
```

### Update

The `TAPi18n._` was renamed to `TAPi18n.__`.

THX [/u/kvnmrz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6139695/kvnmrz) for the hint.

Comment: Well indeed that's a possibility, but in order to avoid to have several long mail text on my JS file, I'd like to access the .json and go through it.

Isn't there a way to do something like i18n.getLanguage().emailsText.mailConfirmation ? As I would do {{_ "emailsText.mailConfirmation"}} in HTML

Comment: I extendet my answer, you could also render the mail client-side.

Comment: Oh, not bad ! And so if would build the HTML mail according to the currently selected i18n language ?

Thanks a lot bud !

Comment: I still got a problem... Mail are usually sent from the server (Here, it would be sooo much easier for me to be able to send the mail from the function that handle new notifications). Isn't there a way to get the rendered tempalte from server without having to send it from client ? If i do so, it is gonna be very tricky and ugly :/

Comment: I assume, that you are pushing notifications to specific users. So I updated my answer to include a solution for that case.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. I used SSR package with 1 file per email and lang.... Your solution is so much easier :)